# Process.Exited not always firing

Tags: c#, process

If I run the following code :

```
Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += new System.EventHandler(Process_OnExit);
myProcess.Start();

public static void Process_OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Delete the file on exit
}
```

The event is raised when I exit notepad.  If I try the same code, but I start an image instead :

```
Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg";
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += new System.EventHandler(Process_OnExit);
myProcess.Start();

public static void Process_OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Delete the file on exit
}
```

The event is never fired.  Is it because the process that loads the image is never closed ?

**UPDATE :** The process to start is not always an Image.  It can be anything (pdf, word document, etc).  Maybe my approach isn't right.  Is there any other way to delete the file after the user exited the process ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a temp file. There are functions to create a temp file...

Your event is not firing due to the lack of the process itself, I guess. You can try to use the shell to "start" the document in question but nothing guarantees that there will be a handler for all types of files.

Comment: Yea I think it is a problem with the process. Thx for the help

Answer (score 17):

you should enable raising events for the process.

```
process_name.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: While I forgot it in my code and this answer helped me ;)

Answer (score 5):

For windows media player try the following code

```
 myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "wmplayer";
 myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "yourfilename";
```

For windows picture viewer try this

```
 myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"rundll32.exe";
 myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Windows\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen " + yourfilepath;
```

Now both will give your exited event in Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

You are using the default image viewer in windows since an image file is not executable.  I changed the code to use the XP default and it worked fine.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"rundll32.exe"; 
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\winnt\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen c:\leaf.jpg";
        myProcess.Exited += new System.EventHandler(Process_OnExit); 
        myProcess.Start();
        Console.Read();



    }
    public static void Process_OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("called");
        Console.Read();
    } 


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a generic method.  It may not be always an image.  It can be a PDF, a word document, etc.  I've updated my question.